# Sync locale-data from an API with store using react-redux-i18n

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, internationalization

Is that possible to synchronize a set of translations on-fly with `react-redux-i18n` based on the content of an API?

Now, I'm using a set of translations for several languages (fr, en, es, nl) stored statically in my app, and suit well the translation purpose of the website side of my web application.

For instance, I've got an object for one language (dutch under `locale-data/nl.js`) :

```
export default {
  application: {
    title: 'Toffe app met i18n!',
    hello: 'Hallo, %{name}!'
  },
  date: {
    long: 'D MMMM YYYY'
  },
  export: 'Exporteer %{count} dingen',
  export_0: 'Niks te exporteren',
  export_1: 'Exporteer %{count} ding',
  two_lines: 'Regel 1<br />Regel 2',
  action: {
    sign_up: 'Registreren',
    sign_out: 'Afmelden',
    log_in: 'Aanmelden',
    dashboard: 'Dashboard'
  }
}
```

equivalent for en under `locale-data/en.js`

```
export default {
  application: {
    title: 'Awesome app with i18n!',
    hello: 'Hello, %{name}!'
  },
  date: {
    long: 'MMMM Do, YYYY'
  },
  export: 'Export %{count} items',
  export_0: 'Nothing to export',
  export_1: 'Export %{count} item',
  two_lines: 'Line 1<br />Line 2',
  action: {
    sign_up: 'Sign Up',
    sign_out: 'Sign Out',
    log_in: 'Log In',
    dashboard: 'Dashboard'
  }
}
```

And by using the embedded methods, I can define which is default language in my app at initialization :

```
// locale-data/index.js    
import fr from './fr'
import en from './en'
import nl from './nl'
import es from './es'


// in index.js
...
export default { fr, en, nl, es }

import translations_data from './locale-data'

const translationsObject = {
  ...translations_data
}


syncTranslationWithStore(store)
store.dispatch(loadTranslations(translationsObject))
store.dispatch(setLocale('en'))
```

The problem is, that if I want to use a large collection of string for each language, it'll drastically slow down my front-end application. Is that possible to load only some languages at the beginning (e.g : english) and updating the store when an user triggers a redux action, so it'd resync from an API the required translations?

Comment: spoiler -> but react-i18next offers that https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next -> loading translation via xhr - just load languages needed, just load tanslations file needed (you can spilt those into multiple files).

Comment: Seems like the answer to my problems :)